# Unable to load the "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRenderer" runtime

Tags: php, symfony, google-app-engine

I've been working through various hurtles toward migrating an existing Symfony3 web app from a local LAMP host up to Goggle's App Engine Standard PHP Environment.  I've taken hints from the [appengine-symfony-starter-project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-symfony-starter-project) to use Memcache for sessions, pre-cache the application code, and connect to a Cloud SQL MySQL database. In have the core pieces working fine.

I added a login form at `/login` using a TWIG template with a form in it that goes like so:

```
<form class="form" action="{{ path('security_login') }}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="email" type="text" name="_email" placeholder="Email" value="{{ last_username }}"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" name="_password" placeholder="Password"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" checked>
    <label for "remember_me">Remember Me</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-round btn-b">Login</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><a href="{{ path('security_reset') }}">Forgot Password?</a></div>
</form>
```

This works fine in the local DEV and TEST environments but when I push this up to GAE, I'm getting the error below:

```
Unable to load the "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRenderer" runtime.
```

I've been digging for a couple hours now and haven't found a hit as to what's wrong here.  Anyone have any ideas where to look?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I can't duplicate that error, but are you enabling  the `framework.templating.engines: ['twig']` in app/config.yml?  And does your composer.lock file have twig/twig listed?  Also, clear your cache.

Comment: Other pages that use Twig templates are working fine to I'm thinking that's not the issue. Following along with that starter-project I linked earlier, some extra steps were taken so the cache-warmup works and we don't have to do any writes to the filesystem once deployed since that's not allowed. I'm worries some more warmup may be needed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case "twig.strict_variables: true" to "twig.strict_variables: false" fixed an issue.

Comment: Doesn't seem to affect the issue for me. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Can you try "twig.strict_variables: false" in config of production?

Comment: I have.  Also modified AppBundle\TwigTwig\Environment::getOptionsHash() to just remove it.  Neither approach resolves the issue for me.

Comment: I’ve made update to composer and the issue is fixed on its own. Think there were some hot fixes made. Can you try it? Just really curious

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same error this morning at work, in a Silex app.

This helped us: https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/pull/1571

It worked for us to change in our composer.json the version of `symfony/form` from `~2.8|^3.0` to `~2.8|3.3` as it appears TwigRenderer is deprecated in 3.4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Been fiddling and have upgraded to SF 3.4.1. I am now getting the same error except it's complaining about not being able to load Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer instead of TwigRenderer.